# XML print text of child tag below two parents

Tags: python, xml, parsing, parent, children

Here is my xml. I only want to print out `status` `result` and `type` text from childern.

```
<response status="success">
  <result>
    <job>
      <tenq>2022/11/04 17:10:58</tenq>
      <tdeq>17:10:58</tdeq>
      <id>2054</id>
      <user>mradmin</user>
      <type>Commit</type>
      <status>ACT</status>
      <queued>NO</queued>
      <stoppable>yes</stoppable>
      <result>PEND</result>
      <tfin />
      <description />
      <positionInQ>0</positionInQ>
      <progress>3</progress>
      <warnings />
      <details />
      <clients>
        <entry name="ha_agent">
          <priority>25</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="sslmgr">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="authd">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="cryptod">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="dagger">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="cord">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="logd">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="reportd">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="useridd">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="distributord">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <entry name="iotd">
          <priority>10</priority>
          <state>init</state>
          <progress>0</progress>
        </entry>
        <overallstatus>init</overallstatus>
        <overallprogress>0</overallprogress>
      </clients>
    </job>
  </result>
</response>
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  

response_status = '<response status="success"><result><job><tenq>2022/11/04 17:10:58</tenq><tdeq>17:10:58</tdeq><id>2054</id><user>mradmin</user><type>Commit</type><status>ACT</status><queued>NO</queued><stoppable>yes</stoppable><result>PEND</result><tfin></ tfin><description></description><positionInQ>0</positionInQ><progress>3</progress><warnings></warnings><details></details><clients><entry name="ha_agent"><priority>25</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="sslmgr"><priority>10</ priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="authd"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="cryptod"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry            name="dagger"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="cord"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="logd"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="reportd"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="useridd"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="distributord"><priority>10</priority><state>init</     state><progress>0</progress></entry><entry name="iotd"><priority>10</priority><state>init</state><progress>0</progress></entry><overallstatus>init</overallstatus><overallprogress>0</overallprogress></clients></job></result></response>'                                                                                                                                                                          
root = ET.fromstring(response_status)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
for child in root.find(".//job"):                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    print(child.tag, child.text)
```

This prints out the following:

```
enq 2022/11/04 17:10:58
tdeq 17:10:58
id 2054
user mradmin
type Commit
status ACT
queued NO
stoppable yes
result PEND
tfin None
description None
positionInQ 0
progress 3
warnings None
details None
clients None
```

But I cant figure out how to narrow down my search only to print out the text only for `status`, `result`, and `type`.

I tried following the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) but the syntax for using findall does not make sense to me. I tried using `./result/job/status`, `.//job/status`, `.//status`, `[status]`, and `[tag='status']`. Nothing works. I know this is something I am doing wrong but its just not clear to me. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
for child in root.findall('.//job'):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    print(child.find('type').text)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    print(child.find('status').text)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    print(child.find('result').text)
```

prints out

```
Commit
ACT
PEND
```

Comment: Consider [**`findtext`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext) with *default* argument to avoid errors when named elements do not exist.